# Browser is not ouputting webpage with textbox and submit button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have written a CSS/HTML code which is supposed to show the images of three cars and when you click on an image, a text box appears and you can write comments about the car into the text box and click on the submit button. I have checked and rechecked my codes and everything seems to be in order. I have saved the codes in the htdocs folder of XAMPP. Now, no PHP is involved in my codes, so I don't need a server to execute the file, but as far as I know, this should not matter. So, I type "localhost/index1.php" into the address bar and press return. What I get, surprisingly, is just the images of the three cars, but no submit button. And when I place my pointer on each car, the individual car image gets bigger (as expected) BUT a textbox does NOT appear. This should not be happening. So I decided to rename my file index1.html and saved it in the htdocs folder as before but STILL the situation persists. Please could someone tell me why I am not getting the textbox to appear when I click on the icon, and why no submit button appears either?

*I HAVE NOW ADDED JavaScript to my code, and it's STILL not working!!!*

```
<!DOCTYPE html> <html> <head> <style> body {
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
}
#form {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
.car {
  float: left;
  margin: 2% 2% 5% 2%;
}
.car label img {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
.car label img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.comment {
  position: absolute;
  visibility: hidden;
}
.comment input {
  width: 128px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.car label img {
  width: 128px;
  display: block;
}
#button {
  position: relative;
  left: 66%;
  margin: 2%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
</style> </head>

   
<div id="form">
  <form method="post" action="#">

    <div class="car">
      <label for="mercedesbenz">
        <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9">
      </label>
      <div class="comment">
        <input type="text" id="mercedesbenz" placeholder="Merc" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <label for="porche">
        <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9">
      </label>
      <div class="comment">
        <input type="text" id="Porche" placeholder="Porc" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <label for="bmw">
        <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9">
      </label>
      <div class="comment">
        <input type="text" id="bmw" placeholder="Beemer" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <input id="button" type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</div>




 <script>
 $('.car').click(function() {
 $('.comment').css("visibility", "hidden");
 $('#button').css("visibility", "hidden");

 var id = $(this).children('label').attr('for');
 var buttonOffset;
 switch(id) {
    case 'mercedesbenz':
        buttonOffset = '0';
        break;
    case 'porche':
        buttonOffset = '33%';
        break;
    case 'bmw':
        buttonOffset = '66%';
        break;
}

$(this).children('.comment').css("visibility", "visible");
$('#button').css("left", buttonOffset);
$('#button').css("visibility", "visible");
});

$('.comment').mouseleave(function() {
  setTimeout(function () {
    $('.comment').css("visibility", "hidden");
    $('#button').css("visibility", "hidden");
    }, 500);
});

</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: if no php is involved, why did you use a php tag on the question?

Comment: You have no code of any kind to make the textbox appear.

Comment: Changing the extension will do nothing if there's no JS code to show the textbox on click. You don't see the submit button or the text box because they both are hidden in the CSS (`visibility:hidden`).

Comment: at bare minimal you'll need javascript to make the textboxes appear (server side seems overkill for just showing textboxes, if you're storing the input from the textboxes however, that's a little different story...)

Comment: Jay, thanks. Alvaro and user2366842, you are both correct, I need JS and jQuery for this.

Comment: See the answer I posted for an example with JavaScript working.

Comment: Most probably, the reason that it is not working for you is because you are not including jQuery. If you are, check the console for errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that what you need is JavaScript to handle the click events:

- When you click on an image: show the submit button and the comment box.
- When you click on the submit button: hide the button and the comment box.

Note: I changed your button from type `submit` to `button` so you can see the effect. You should put it back as `submit` on your side.

```js
// show comment box when clicking on image
$("img").on("click", function() {
  $(".comment").css({visibility:"hidden"});
  $(".comment." + $(this).parent().attr("for")).css({visibility:"visible"});
  $("#button").css({visibility:"visible"});
});

// hide button and comment when submitting
$("#button").on("click", function() {
  $(".comment").css({visibility:"hidden"});
  $("#button").css({visibility:"hidden"});
});
```

```css
body {
  background-color: #ADD8E6;
}
#form {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  margin-right: -50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%)
}
.car {
  float: left;
  margin: 2% 2% 5% 2%;
}
.car label img {
  transform: scale(0.8);
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
}
.car label img:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  transform: scale(1);
}
.comment {
  position: absolute;
  visibility:hidden;
}
.comment input {
  width: 128px;
  font-size: 1em;
}
.car label img {
  width: 128px;
  display: block;
}
#button {
  position: relative;
  left: 66%;
  margin: 2%;
  visibility: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="form">
  <form method="post" action="#">

    <div class="car">
      <label for="mercedesbenz">
        <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9">
      </label>
      <div class="comment mercedesbenz">
        <input type="text" id="mercedesbenz" placeholder="Merc" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <label for="porche">
        <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9">
      </label>
      <div class="comment porche">
        <input type="text" id="porche" placeholder="Porc" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="car">
      <label for="bmw">
        <img src="http://tinyurl.com/on964r9">
      </label>
      <div class="comment bmw">
        <input type="text" id="bmw" placeholder="Beemer" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <input id="button" type="button" name="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>

</div>
```

Comment: Glad it worked. If it solved your problem, mark it as the solution.

Comment: Alvaro, I've marked your answer as the solution. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1):

```
.comment {
    position: absolute;
}
```

You have comment boxes hidden

Change your submit button css to:

```
#button {
   position: relative;
   left: 66%;
   margin: 2%;
}
```

Thus, here is the complete version:

http://jsfiddle.net/2khqdxtr/1/